# Use Glassfish embedded with MySQL

Tags: mysql, glassfish-embedded

Well, the title says almost everything, how can I define a jdbc-connection in an embedded glassfish to be able to use a MySQL database as a jdbc resource??

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, it was simpler than I thought!

I've used a jdbc I had configured with an installed glassfish and copied the configuration from domain.xml.

For the embedded glassfish to be able to use MySql driver, I just put the dependency in maven...